# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir when installing sth with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Everytime I try to install something with npm (in this case electron-packager) I run into this error. How can I solve this issue?

I have already tried to give me access by changing the permissions on .npm via chmod, but it didn't work and I also tried it with another node version (installed via nvm: node -v 12.1.0; npm  -v 6.9.0) and it didn`t work as well.

```
$ npm install electron-packager --save-dev
npm ERR! path /Users/felixmoser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/15/a0
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/felixmoser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/15/a0'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/felixmoser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/15/a0'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/felixmoser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/15/a0'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: '/Users/felixmoser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/15/a0'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir ' +
npm ERR!     "'/Users/felixmoser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/15/a0'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/felixmoser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/15/a0',
npm ERR!   parent: 'electron-packager'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/felixmoser/.npm/_logs/2019-05-01T14_11_08_530Z-debug.log
```

I actually don't know what else I should try now and hope, that you guys can help me solve this problem!

Comment: did you changed the node/npm version

Answer (score 25, accepted):

change the ownership of **.npm** folder,
In my case I couldn't figure out the solution so I used

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Comment: much better -` $(whoami)`

Answer (score 8):

Just change the owner of `~/.npm` folder to yourself:

```sh
sudo chown -R felixmoser ~/.npm
```

You'll need to enter your password for calling `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked. My bad was that I added a ":" after the username without specifying the group.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a similar problem with permissions when trying to install packages globally with `--global` or `-g`. I know it's not your current problem, but I want to add it here because people googling the EACCESS when doing a global install might reach this question as well.

Some people change the system folder privileges allowing non-root users writing in system folder, however here is what they recommend in the documentation:

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally/

Back up your computer (including it here because documentation mentions is too, but it feels to me overly cautious)

Then execute:

```sh
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

Edit your **~/.profile**:

```sh
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Then invoke it with

```sh
source ~/.profile
```

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

```
npm install -g jshint
```

Or instead of modifying ~/.profile just use the corresponding ENV variable (but to make it pernament you would have to modify the profile file anyway)

```
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

Comment: this feels like the correct approach and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and none of the solutions were working until I realized....I forgot to run `npm init` first. Without a package.json, npm install anything wouldn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Simply add `sudo`
So instead of `npm install electron-packager --save-dev`
Let it be `sudo npm install electron-packager --save-dev`

Comment: Do not recommend running npm with sudo! Always be very precise when handing out permissions. Recommend previous answer!

Answer (score -3):

Please consider running the instructions at least inside the user's location, for example:

/home/myuser/

express HelloWorld --view=pug

Comment: He is using it in the user's folder, but the npm install does try to write access to different folders.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Roberto :) As Anton has already posted this is not the issue in this case. It wouldn't matter from where you run it. Apparently npm was run with sudo once before and thus the .npm folder is not owned by the user running it. So the only option working is (and avoiding to run with sudo every time which is bad practice) is to change the owner of the .npm folder back to the user executing npm. Thank you for your input though. And don't be discouraged by the downvotes. They simply mark less optimal answers vs optimal ones. Post more answers! It will come to you :)