# Permission denied while trying to install Create React App with NPM

Tags: npm, terminal, create-react-app

I've been trying to install Create React App using NPM and it's giving me a permission denied error:

[image: terminal screenshot]

I force cleaned NPM cache and it did not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938030/error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-when-installing-sth-with-npm Same problem you're having. Your user that is executing npm command doesn't have write permission to that directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir when installing sth with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938030/error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-when-installing-sth-with-npm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
sudo chown -R dhananjayjoshi /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create React App** doesn't suggest anymore to install with NPM you should use [NPX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) so you don't need to `sudo` anything.

Note:

> npx on the first line is not a typo — it’s a package runner tool that comes with npm 5.2+.

Command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Reference the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)