# Installing components... EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/components'

Tags: next.js, ubuntu-22.04, next.js14, shadcnui

I am using shadcn/ui components to create frontend in my NextJS 14 project. But I am getting this error(ubuntu 22.04), when I try to add any component using following command: `npx shadcn-ui@latest add navigation-menu`

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938030/error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-when-installing-sth-with-npm) also, but still issue persists. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Expected behavior: It should create a navigation-menu.jsx file under src/components/ui folder if command runs successfully.

Comment: Solution: I updated paths value in the jsconfig.json from 
`"paths": { "@/*": ["/*"] }` to `"paths": { "@/*": ["./*"] }` and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a permission issue, in which case, open a terminal in the folder that contains the project and run:

```bash
sudo chmod u+w project-folder-name
```

Also, as Meet Akbari said, it could be an import aliases issue, problem, in which case you need to update your `jsconfig.json` accordingly:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": { "@/*": ["./*"] }
  }
}
```